# How to use ggRandomForests dependence plots for caret model in R?

Tags: r, plot, regression, r-caret

I want to create a facet of partial dependence plots for my model using the `gg_variable` function from `ggRandomForests` package. I have the following but it does not work.

**How can I do this?**

```
library("caret")
library("ggRandomForests")
library("randomForest") 
data("iris")
iris$Species<-NULL
control = trainControl(method="cv", number=5,savePredictions = TRUE)  
in_train= createDataPartition(iris$Sepal.Length, p=.66, list=FALSE) 
train_st=iris[in_train,]
test_st=iris[-in_train,] 
trf_sep = train(Sepal.Length ~ .,
          data=train_st,ntree=800,method="rf",metric="Rsquared",trControl=control,importance = TRUE)
gg_variable(trf_sep)#Here is the problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gg_variable` requires output from `randomForest` model. It does not work with the output of `caret::train` function. Under such situation you can use the `train` function from `caret` package to tune mtry and fit the random forest model with `randomForest` package with tuned mtry and then apply `gg_variable` on that like

```
library("caret")
library("ggRandomForests")
library("randomForest") 
data("iris")
iris$Species<-NULL
control = trainControl(method="cv", number=5,savePredictions = TRUE)  
in_train= createDataPartition(iris$Sepal.Length, p=.66, list=FALSE) 
train_st=iris[in_train,]
test_st=iris[-in_train,] 
trf_sep = train(Sepal.Length ~ .,
                data=train_st,ntree=800,method="rf",metric="Rsquared",trControl=control,importance = TRUE)
try <- randomForest(Sepal.Length ~ .,
             data=train_st,ntree=800, mtry=3)

 gg_dta <- gg_variable(try)

plot(gg_dta, xvar=c("Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"), 
     panel=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply but I am not sure that your suggestion works. I do not get any plot, just a message "`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'". Is that what you get from your code too?